# Classic asp show checked values in checkbox from comma separated values

Tags: asp-classic

I have the checked values as comma seperated values in database.When next time user visits the page I need to show the checked values from comma seperated values so user can update them and again submit them.
Here is my code:
/*ArrayValues="PMT/HLBRs,ROM,Development" (not putting database part here)*/

```
     ArrayValues=Split(objRSComment.fields("Phase"),",")
     for i=0 to 8 
     Response.Write "Value " & i & " is " & ArrayValues(i) & "<br>"
     Next 
     response.end() 
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="PMT/HLBRs"  "checked"/><label>PMT/HLBRs</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="ROM" "checked"/><label>ROM</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="BUS CASE APPROVAL" <%=chkVal% >/><label>BUS CASE APPROVAL</label> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="Detailed Requirements" /><label>Detailed Requirements</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="20% LOE"/><label>20% LOE</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="Development"/><label>Development</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="Testing"/><label>Testing</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="Implementation"/><label>Implementation</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="Post Deployment Monitoring"/><label>Post Deployment Monitoring</label>
```

I have to show "PMT/HLBRs,ROM,Development" these values as selected in checkboxes and others with out checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a simple instring search

```
<%
dim phaseList = objRSComment.fields("Phase")

function isChecked(phase)
   dim retVal = ""

   if inStr(phaseList, phase) > 0 then  
      retval = " checked "  
   end if
   isChecked = retVal

end function

ArrayValues=Split(objRSComment.fields("Phase"),",")
     for i=0 to 8 
     Response.Write "Value " & i & " is " & ArrayValues(i) & "<br>"
     Next 
%>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="PMT/HLBRs" <%= isChecked("PMT/HLBRs") %>/><label>PMT/HLBRs</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="ROM" <%= isChecked("ROM") %>/><label>ROM</label>
     ... etc
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkProjPhase" value="Post Deployment Monitoring" <%= isChecked("Post Deployment Monitoring") %>/><label>Post Deployment Monitoring</label>
```

**Caution**  if you have phases which are derived from eachother this will not work as expected. I.e. if you have a phases such as `housing` and `housing loans`, housing would be checked if  housing loan was in the list of phases